# Pause All Media

Tags: keyboard, audio, music

I typically either use a keyboard or a button on my mouse to play/pause media. I also have a habit of switching between youtube and spotify. Sometimes, I have white noise (youtube) and music (spotify) playing at the same time.

If someone walks up and needs to talk, the pause command from either keyboard or mouse only pauses one media stream, or the focus doesn't follow the stream I last interacted with. It's like I have to trigger the play/pause command a few times to show the dedicated pause button where I'm at. Example: I am playing music and white noise as described above. I move my chair, hearing something. I want to pause everything to listen to the room to hear what it was.... Only the video (white noise) stops, but the music continues.

is there a way to pause all media in any way? Mute button doesn't count because I then miss out on what is being said or playing or whatever. Or, is there a way to reliably tie the command to one app?

note: this isn't about changing the behavior or enabling the F8 function Key, nor about binding commands to keys.. I know that stuff.. just wondering if there's a master pause command or "stop all". If I pull out my airpods, I think everything stops, but I don't always reach for that first (forget I have them in)